# numpy under a groupby not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/test.csv')
df.drop(['SecurityID'],1,inplace=True)                         

Time = 1
trade_filter_size = 9
groupbytime = (str(Time) + "min")
df['dateTime_s'] = df['dateTime'].astype('datetime64[s]')
df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'])
df[str(Time)+"min"] = df['dateTime'].dt.floor(str(Time)+"min")
df['tradeBid'] = np.where(((df['tradePrice'] <= df['bid1']) & (df['isTrade']==1)), df['tradeVolume'], 0)

groups = df[df['isTrade'] == 1].groupby(groupbytime)                        
print("groups",groups.dtypes)

#THIS IS WORKING
df_grouped = (groups.agg({
            'tradeBid': [('sum', np.sum),('downticks_number', lambda x: (x > 0).sum())],
            }))

# creating a new data frame which is filttered
df2 = pd.DataFrame( df.loc[(df['isTrade'] == 1) & (df['tradeVolume']>=trade_filter_size)])
#recalculating all the bid/ask volume to be bsaed on the filter size
df2['tradeBid'] = np.where(((df2['tradePrice'] <= df2['bid1']) & (df2['isTrade']==1)), df2['tradeVolume'], 0)


df2grouped = (df2.agg({
      # here is the problem!!! NOT WORKING
      'tradeBid': [('sum', np.sum), lambda x: (x > 0).sum()],
       }))
```

The same function is used `tradeBid': [('sum', np.sum),('downticks_number', lambda x: (x > 0).sum())`. In the first time it's working ok but when doing it on filtered data in a new df it's causing an error:

> ValueError: downticks_number is an unknown string function

when I use this code instead to solve the above

```
  'tradeBid': [('sum', np.sum), lambda x: (x > 0).sum()],
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: cannot combine transform and aggregation operations

Any idea why I get different results for the same usage of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there were 2 conditions to match for the 2nd groupby, I solved this by moving the filter into the df by creating a new column which is used as a filter (with both 2 filters).
than there was no problem to groupby
the order was the problem